# Xamarin.Forms: XAML property pass-through

Tags: xamarin.forms, inotifypropertychanged

How do I pass property values to custom control children without writing code?

Content page:

```
<views:ButtonView Image="newViolationSmall.png" Text="{Binding ParentsText}/>
```

Then ButtonView.xaml

```
<StackLayout 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="SmartwebsCrossPlatform.Portable.Views.ButtonView">

    <Button Image="{Binding Image}"/>
    <Label Text="{Binding Text}" />

</StackLayout>
```

And ButtonView.cs

```
public partial class ButtonView : StackLayout {

...

    //text
    public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty = BindableProperty.Create( "Text", typeof( string ), typeof( ButtonView ), null, BindingMode.Default, null, null, null, null );
    public string Text {
        get {
            return (string)GetValue( TextProperty );
        }
        set {
            SetValue( TextProperty, value );
        }
    }

    //image
    public static readonly BindableProperty ImageProperty = BindableProperty.Create( "Image", typeof( string ), typeof( ButtonView ) );
    public string Image {
        get {
            return (string)GetValue( ImageProperty );
        }
        set {
            SetValue( ImageProperty, value );
        }
    }
```

This does not show any text or image. A rather annoying alternative is to name both Button and Label, override ButtonView.OnPropertyChanged, and explicitly set their properties from code but it causes a System.ObjectDisposedException (Object name: 'Android.Graphics.Bitmap') when I navigate around this page.

@yyou's solution works for const values, but not for parent's properties.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing missing is to set the BindingContext of this custom layout.
ie.

```
   //ButtonView.xaml.cs
        public ButtonView ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
            BindingContext = this;
        }

    //to use this ButtonView component in a page
    //ie. DetailPage.xaml
    <ContentPage  ...>

        <app2:ButtonView Text="{Binding ParentText}" Image="{Binding ButtonImage }"/>

    </ContentPage>

//in DetailPage.xaml.cs
    public DetailPage() {
        InitializeComponent ();
        BindingContext = new DetailViewModel() {
                ParentText = "sjldfdkfdjd",
                ButtonImage = "my-button-image.png"
        };
    }

    //in the file DetailViewModel.cs
    namespace App2.ViewModels
    {
        public class DetailViewModel : BaseViewModel {
            private string _parentText;
            public string ParentText {
                get { return _parentText; }
                set { SetProperty<string>(ref _parentText, value); }
            }

        private string _buttonImage;
        public string ButtonImage {
            get { return _buttonImage; }
            set { SetProperty<string>(ref _buttonImage, value); }
        }

        //other stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: That works with const values, but how do I pass a value from parent binding? E.g. <views:ButtonView Image="newViolationSmall.png" Text="{Binding ParentsText}" />. It gives me property not found on 'ButtonView', target property: ParentsText.

Comment: @AntonDuzenko i have updated my answer. the ParentsText should be a property of parent BindingContext object.

Comment: Did you test this? Because to me it tries to look for ParentText property in ButtonView, not in DetailPage.

Comment: Binding: 'NewViolationCommand' property not found on 'SmartwebsCrossPlatform.Portable.Views.ButtonView', target property: 'SmartwebsCrossPlatform.Portable.Views.ButtonView.ButtonCommand'